# How to check the input of a user from a form input box using php and html corresponds to a result from the database in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

**This is the problem**

> user is supposed to enter a code that should be verified by an SQL statement in the database using Php.
>
> //this code should check that the code that the user enters in the
>   confirmation input field is the same as that in the database.
>
> //it collects different fields in the database from different tables
>
> //Here is the form input box where I should enter the confirmation

**code**

```
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-money"></i></span>


//this is the entry box named con_code

        <input type="text" name="con_code" id="con_code" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Enter you Confirmation Code" />
    </div>
```

**The php statements**

```
<?php 
// the SQL statement to check from the tables
    $check="SELECT payment.instname, payment.firstname, payment.lastname, payment.email, payment.amount, payment.category, payment.confcode, payment.tdate, transactions.transactioncode FROM payment, transactions WHERE payment.confcode='con_code'";

//query to the db
    $result= mysqli_query($conn,$check);

//checks whether the SQL statement is true

    if($result-> num_rows > 0){
        //$conf=$row['confcode'];
        //$amt=$row['amount'];
        //$date=$row['tdate'];
        $msg = "Payment has been Confirmed!!";

//output if the condition is true
        echo $msg; 
    }
    else{

//output if the condition is false
        $ms="Payment Code does not exist!!";
        echo $ms; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: So what's the problem? There's no problem, just no implementation.

Comment: The problem is not really clear. What is not working as expected?

Comment: would you be so kind as to not use blockquote `>` for text? and to edit those out please?

Comment: No problem here.

Comment: The problem is in the Sql statement where im giving the WHERE condition. It keeps saying "  Notice: Undefined index: con_code "

Answer (score -1):

**Simplified:-** !!!No Security!!!

```
$con_code = $_POST['con_code'];

$check="SELECT payment.instname, payment.firstname, payment.lastname, payment.email, payment.amount,payment.category, payment.confcode, payment.tdate, transactions.transactioncode
     FROM payment, transactions
     WHERE payment.confcode='".$con_code."'";
```

Comment: Its still not picking data from the text box

Comment: is there a way we could use ajax to pull the data from the database so that as the user enters the code it displays whether or not it has verified the data